# filling a dataframe column using iterrows and a reference dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, numpy

I have this dataframe:

```
d = {'HP': ['Eu',np.nan, 'Ma'], 'DK': ['A','B','C']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I am now trying to create a function which will update the Nan Values of the column HP according to the dictionary translation of the column 'DK'
I tried this :

```
def fill_HP(df):
    dictt={'A':'Eu','B':'Ma','C':'Ve'}
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(row['HP']):
            df.at(i,'HP')=dictt(row['DK'])
```

so, logically, I want the NaN filled with "Ma".

I get an error message reading: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call pointing at my "df.at" statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `df.HP.fillna(df.DK.map(dictt), inplace=True)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use square brackets -

```
def fill_HP(df):
    dictt={'A':'Eu','B':'Ma','C':'Ve'}
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if pd.isnull(row['HP']):
            df.at[i,'HP']=dictt[row['DK']]
```

Comment: For `dictt[row['DK']]` as well.